# Sum of air compressors

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

I think this is so basic that I need to apologize first, but I googled it a lot and maybe it's that I don't know how to express my question to an algorithm.

The thing is that I'm very rusty in physics.

I have a water tank that I need to pressurize to a max pressure of 110 psi, I thought that i could solved it by connecting the tank to two air compressors in sequence, each of which has a max pressure output of 70 psi. Will this give me an output of 140 psi? Or will they just work with more ease at 70 psi.

If the output is still 70 psi, how can I obtain the 40 psi missing using 70 psi air compressors?

I've search for other types of air compressors but the ones with 70 psi are easier to use for my ultimate goal (electronics).

Comment: This is really about engineering, not physics.  I can say that no, you probably shouldn't do that and it may not work.  In theory it might; but the compressors may not be rated to perform properly at 110 psi.  Look up "compressors in series" to see more information on what you're proposing. and why you probably shouldn't.

Comment: If you can get an gas tight connection from the output of one to the input of the other, it might work. The issue is that the motor on the second one might  not have enough force to move the piston against 110 psi. The seals on the piston might also not be capable of holding the pressure. I would expect that even if it works, the service life of the second compressor will be short.

Comment: Be careful. Your compressors may not be rated to handle much more back pressure than they could create on their own. If they're not rated for high back pressure, the best-case scenario is that you blew out two compressors. The alternatives are far worse.

Comment: @probably_someone thank you i'll take it into account.